Uncountably many non-zero divisors in $\mathrm{spec}(a)$ for a non-algebraic element over $\mathbb{C}$
Let $A$ be a finitely-generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and let $a$ be a non-algebraic element in $A$. So according to the spectral theorem, $\mathrm{spec}(a)$ is uncountable. How does one show that there are uncountably many elements which are not zero divisors but also not invertible?
I know that in the case of algebraic elements there are finitely many elements in $\mathrm{spec}(a)$ where most of these are zero divisors. So I am a bit confused about where to go from here for non-algebraic elements.
Thanks!

Is $A$ commutative? Do you use the definition of $\mathrm{spec}(a) = {\lambda : a - \lambda 1 \notin A^{\times}}$? Why the tag "algebraic geometry"?
